# Do I need to free memory returned from a C function called via CFFI?

Tags: python, c, memory-management, free, python-cffi

I have this example code that has a function `text()` returning a newly allocated string:

```
ffi_test = FFI()
ffi_test.set_source('_test', '''
char* test() { return strdup("hello world"); }
''')
ffi_test.cdef('''
char* test();
void free(void *);
''')
ffi_test.compile(verbose=True)
```

This works fine:

```
In [1]: from _test import ffi, lib
In [2]: x = lib.test()
In [3]: ffi.string(x)
Out[3]: b'hello world'
In [4]: lib.free(x)
```

However, I could not find anything in the docs whether I actually need to manually `free()` the returned string of if CFFI takes ownership of the pointer as soon as it's returned to Python code.

Also, if I do need to manually `free()` it, do I need to expose `free()` in my *cdefs* or is does CFFI provide some nicer way for it?

Comment: When "ownership" of an object is passed from one software component to another, the new owner becomes responsible for freeing the memory. Because *that's what "ownership" means.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation on [Working with pointers, structures and arrays](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#working-with-pointers-structures-and-array), and *quoting the correct section*:

> Any operation that would in C return a pointer or array or struct type gives you a fresh cdata object. **Unlike the “original” one, these fresh cdata objects don’t have ownership**

Therefore you must free it, there is no way it can assume the ownership:
In C there are many functions that return a pointer to a *constant string in memory*, that not only it is not dynamically allocated, it is not allocated, or modifiable at all, for example. Freeing those would be very erroneous.

---

Also for `free`, the documentation says the following:

> An alternative is to declare and call the C malloc() and free() functions, or some variant like mmap() and munmap(). Then you control exactly when the memory is allocated and freed. For example, add these two lines to your existing ffibuilder.cdef():
>
> ```
> void *malloc(size_t size);
> void free(void *ptr);
> ```

Since it is very important that the **correct** C standard library `free` is used for a pointer returned by `strdup` you cannot rely CFFI to magically do the correct thing, but instead as you suspected, you should expose `free()`. You can also use the `gc` as suggested by Barmar to register an automatic clean up, if needed:

```
x = ffi.gc(x, lib.free)
```

Comment: Thanks! That's the part in the docs I missed. Now there's only the second part remaining - i.e. whether I need to expose `free()` like I did above or if CFFI does this automatically (`lib.free` doesn't exist though if I don't manually expose it in my cdef)

Comment: If you know the object was dynamically allocated with `malloc()`, you could use `ffi.gc()` to register `lib.free` to reclaim it.