# AttributeError: free when taking ownership or freeing cdata

Tags: python, python-cffi

If I want to take ownership of a pointer that was `malloc`ed in C, the [docs for the Python `cffi` package](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47080571/1485877) say to use `ffi.gc` with `lib.free` as the destructor. However, when I do this, I get `AttributeError: free` on the call to `lib.free`. Where is `lib.free` defined?

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

from cffi import FFI

common_header = """
typedef struct {
  int32_t length;
  double* values;
} my_struct;
"""

# FFI
ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef(common_header + """
int func(my_struct*);
""")
ffi.set_source('_temp', common_header + """
int func(my_struct *input) {
  double* values = malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
  input->length = 3;
  input->values = values;
  return 0;
}
""")

with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    lib_path = ffi.compile(tmpdir=temp_dir)

    lib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)

    func = lib.func

# Using the library
my_struct = ffi.new('my_struct*')
func(my_struct)

# Taking ownership of the malloced member
global_weakkey = WeakKeyDictionary()
global_weakkey[my_struct] = ffi.gc(my_struct.values, lib.free)
# AttributeError: free
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs don't hammer this point, but you need to expose `free` as part of your lib's `cdef`s just like any other function in order to access it on the Python side. Put `void free(void *ptr);` in the call to `ffi.cdef` and the `free` function will be available via `lib.free` after compilation:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

from cffi import FFI

common_header = """
typedef struct {
  int32_t length;
  double* values;
} my_struct;
"""

# FFI
ffi = FFI()

ffi.cdef(common_header + """
int func(my_struct*);
void free(void *ptr); // <-- Key to lib.free working later
""")
ffi.set_source('_temp', common_header + """
int func(my_struct *input) {
  double* values = malloc(sizeof(double) * 3);
  input->length = 3;
  input->values = values;
  return 0;
}
""")

with TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
    lib_path = ffi.compile(tmpdir=temp_dir)

    lib = ffi.dlopen(lib_path)

    func = lib.func

# Using the library
my_struct = ffi.new('my_struct*')
func(my_struct)

# Taking ownership of the malloced member
global_weakkey = WeakKeyDictionary()
global_weakkey[my_struct] = ffi.gc(my_struct.values, lib.free)
```